# Difference between TextView and MaterialTextView?

Tags: android, textview, material-components-android

I know about difference between TextView and AppCompatTextView. But what about TextView and MaterialTextView? What are the nuances? And when we need to use MaterialTextView?

Answer (score 9):

According to the official documentation [here](https://material.io/develop/android/supporting/text-view)

> MaterialTextView supports all of the standard attributes that can be
> changed for an AppCompatTextView. Unlike the AppCompatTextView which
> supports specifying the line height only in a view layout XML,
> MaterialTextView supports the ability to read the line height from a
> TextAppearance style, which can be applied to the MaterialTextView
> either using the style attribute or using the android:textAppearance
> attribute

.