# What's the difference between AppCompact and Material Design?

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I'm looking to learn the difference between Material Component and Androidx AppCompact Component in my android app, for example, the difference between the usage of these two:

```
<androidx.appcompat.*.* />
```

vs

```
<com.google.android.material.*.* />
```

Is there a difference between these two or some recommendation on which is preferable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between TextView and MaterialTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952756/difference-between-textview-and-materialtextview)

Comment: Yes for TextViews, but i'm looking for all compoenents

Answer (score 0):

1. MaterialTextView supports all o attributes that can be changed for an AppCompatTextView.
2. Unlike the AppCompatTextView which supports specifying the line height only in a view layout XML
3. MaterialTextView supports the ability to read the line height from a TextAppearance style, which can be applied to the MaterialTextView either using the style attribute or using the android:textAppearance attribute

Basically MaterialTextView has more attributes than can be customized

Comment: MaterialTextView is also part of another library that you may or may not be using, and may be styled differently (as it will be a strict implementation of material design, where AppCompatTextView and TextView aren't.